# How do get WMD-Editor to post Markdown to the server and not HTML?

Tags: javascript, markdown, wmd

It seems that WMD-Editor is posting HTML to the server instead of the markdown. How can i get it to send the Markdown?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the master branch of the SO version, the interesting line is line 2341:

`Attacklab.wmd_defaults = {version:1, output:"HTML", lineLength:40, delayLoad:false};`

Change this to ask for markdown instead:

`Attacklab.wmd_defaults = {version:1, output:"markdown", lineLength:40, delayLoad:false};`

.. and you'll get the Markdown instead.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks you have no clue how useful this was.

Answer (score 2):

In [my version (mooWMD)](http://moowmd.awardspace.info/) you have to change the value at line 1343 from 'html' to 'markdown'.
I believe it is the same for the SO version (look for the 'output' configuration value).